# How to take a integer day from date format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want a day in digits from my Current date.for an example

```
if entry_date = August 22, 2011 
due_on = "Due on 22nd"
```

i know the logic of getting suffix,but how to get day value from my current date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get day from current date as follows:

```
NSDate * mCurrentDate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents * weekdayComponents = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: mCurrentDate];
    
    _day    = [weekdayComponents day];
```

This will give you the day component of your current date.

Answer (score 0):

(According to your example) try this ....

```
NSString *entry_date = @"August 22, 2011";
NSString *digits = [entry_date stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
int intDate = [digits intValue]
NSLog(@"Attempts: %d", intDate);
```

Hope its helps you... :D